# ValueError("No variables provided.") in apply_gradients of optimize.py

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

In [optimizer.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py), the first part of code segment is

```
def apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, global_step=None, name=None):

   grads_and_vars = tuple(grads_and_vars)  # Make sure repeat iteration works.
   if not grads_and_vars:
      raise ValueError("No variables provided.")
```

Running my program, I got the error message caused by this specific error. I then printed out `tuple(grads_and_vars)`, part of which is. I don't know why it can cause the error of `no variables provided`.

```
((<tf.Tensor 'Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/_0:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 64) dtype=float32>, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x2afc746b5c50>), (<tf.Tensor 'Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/_1:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x2affd48189b0>), (<tf.Tensor 'Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/_2:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 64) dtype=float32>, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x2affd486d940>), (<tf.Tensor 'Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/_3:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x2affd488cf98>), (<tf.Tensor 'Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/_4:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 128) dtype=float32>, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x2afc746b5d68>), (<tf.Tensor 'Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/_5:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x2affd48f4278>), (<tf.Tensor 'Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/Optimizer/training/clip_by_global_norm/_6:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 128) dtype=float32>, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x2affd4915e10>),
```

Comment: Could you provide some context of the model you are running? Which variables do you have, and which variable this apply_gradients op is for?

Comment: Did you find the solution. I have same error too.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, maybe you should try grads_and_vars = list(zip(grads, var_list))